# How to create a Emacs file that looks/feels likes the Emacs start up page?

Tags: emacs

The Emacs start up page has image, link, and fonts with different size all in one. How can I create a page like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs doesn't come with a mode that can create all those effects (although you can get some of them with [Enriched mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Formatted-Text.html)).  You'd have to write Lisp code to create the page you want.

The actual startup page is created by the function `fancy-startup-screen` in the file `startup.el`.  You can look at that to see how it does what it does.  You'll probably want to read the [Emacs Display chapter](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display.html) of the [Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html).

Note: You can display the startup screen at any time by typing `M-: (fancy-startup-screen) <ENTER>`.  (You can't use `M-x` because it's not marked as an interactive function.)  There's also an "About" screen that is very similar, which can be displayed with "Help > About Emacs" in the menu bar or `C-h C-a` or `M-x display-about-screen`.  (`fancy-about-screen` is the function that actually creates that screen.)